# import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently migrate one project in androidx .This project working fine . Now when i am opening other project in android studio i am found in all other project i am getting error

```
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

these all package not found i have not changed any thing other project . Why android support libraries not workig with other project. Please help me how can i run android support lib again this android studio .I have done already invalide chache and restart and also clean project but no luck

Comment: or replace them with the proper androidX dependency

Comment: @Zun i have given androidx support in specific project but this project occur in other project

Answer (score 6):

You need to use androidX dependencies like this:

```
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

Make sure you have updated your `app.gradle` too

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
```

You also need to add the following to `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Once you update your gradles and delete the old dependencies Android Studio should find the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Add the support library to the dependency section.

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'